# Laravel 4 : getting username instead of id in the index view, Many to Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

I have a friend_users table where I store user_id's from users. Now I want to see who are myfriends, but I don't know how to access the user_username's using eloquent.

index view :

```
@foreach($friend_users as $friend_user)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $friend_user->friend_user_id }}</td>  
       <td>{{ $friend_user->user->user_username }}</td>
       <td>{{ $friend_user->friend->user_username }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

index controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $friend_users = FriendUser::all();

        return View::make('friend_users.index')
            ->with('friend_users', $friend_users);
    }
```

User model :

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friend_users', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

FriendUser model :

```
public function friend() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'friend_id'); 
}

public function user() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have these relations set up in your `FriendUser` model

```
public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('User'); }
public function friend() { return $this->belongsTo('User', 'friend_id'); }
```

**You can eager load your user model(s)** (in your controller):

```
$friend_users = FriendUser::with('user', 'friend')->where('user_id', $yourUserId);

return View::make('friend_users.index', array('friend_users', $friend_users));
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($friend_users as $friend_user)
    <tr>
        // the user info
        <td>{{ $friend_user->user->id}}</td> 
        <td>{{ $friend_user->user->name}}</td>
        // the friend info
        <td>{{ $friend_user->friend->id }}</td>  
        <td>{{ $friend_user->friend->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

By the sound of it, this should suffice for your purpose, but if user_id and friend_id can be interchangeable, you may want to consider a `many to many` relationship instead.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks this helped, I updated my question with the right code for my example.

Comment: In my example I did not have to change the index action in the controller.